# Is there any interpretation of parameters in Holt Winters method?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I am doing forecast on time series on R and I use exponential smoothing method Holt Winters.

Does a value of $\alpha$ close to $0$ or $1$ "mean" something particular about the series?

Same question for $\beta$ and $\gamma$.